# Jobsite scraping with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I'm looking to scrape a website for job description information, but I seem to only be getting only unrelated text. Here's the soup object creation:

```
url = 'https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/boston-full-stack-engineer-jobs-SRCH_IL.0,6_IC1154532_KO7,26.htm?jl=3188635682&guid=0000016a8432102e99e9b5232325d3d5&pos=102&src=GD_JOB_AD&srs=MY_JOBS&s=58&ao=599212'
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"}) 
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(urlopen(req),"html.parser")
divliul=soup.body.findAll(['div','li','ul'])
for i in divliul:
    if i.string is not None:
        print(i.string)
```

If you browse the website for a second, you'll see that the soup seems to only contain elements from the left hand column and nothing from the job description containers. I thought this might be a urllib request issue, but I have tried just downloading the html file and reading it that way and the results are similar.
output:

```
Jobs
Company Reviews
Company Reviews
Companies near you
 Best Buy Reviews in Boston
 Target Reviews in Boston
 IBM Reviews in Boston
 AT&T Reviews in Boston
 The Home Depot Reviews in Boston
 Walmart Reviews in Boston

 Macy's Reviews in Boston
 Microsoft Reviews in Boston
 Deloitte Reviews in Boston
 Amazon Reviews in Boston
 Bank of America Reviews in Boston
 Wells Fargo Reviews in Boston
Company Culture
 Best Places to Work
 12 Companies That Will Pay You to Travel the World
 7 Types of Companies You Should Never Work For
 20 Companies Hiring for the Best Jobs In America
 How to Become the Candidate Recruiters Can’t Resist
 13 Companies With Enviable Work From Home Options
 New On Glassdoor
Salaries
Interviews
Salary Calculator
Account Settings
Account Settings
Account Settings
Account Settings
empty notification btn
My Profile
Saved Jobs
Email & Alerts
Contributions
My Resumes
Company Follows
Account
Help / Contact Us
Account Settings
Account Settings
Account Settings
empty notification btn
For Employers
For Employers
Unlock Employer Account
Unlock Employer Account
Post a Job
Post a Job
Employer Branding
Job Advertising
Employer Blog
Talk to Sales
 Post Jobs Free
Full Stack Engineer Jobs in Boston, MA
Jobs
Companies
Salaries
Interviews
Full Stack Engineer
EASY APPLY
EASY APPLY
Full Stack Engineer | Noodle.com
EASY APPLY
EASY APPLY
Full Stack Engineer
Hot
Software Engineer
EASY APPLY
EASY APPLY
Senior Software Engineer
EASY APPLY
EASY APPLY
We're Hiring
We're Hiring
Full Stack Engineer
Hot
Software Engineer
Hot
Hot
Full Stack Engineer
We're Hiring
Full Stack Software Engineer
EASY APPLY
EASY APPLY
We're Hiring
We're Hiring
Software Engineer
New
New
Full Stack Engineer
EASY APPLY
EASY APPLY
We're Hiring
We're Hiring
Pre-Sales Engineer / Full-Stack Developer
Top Company
Top Company
Full Stack Software Engineer
Software Engineer
Top Company
Top Company
Associate Software Engineer
Full Stack Software Engineer
Software Engineer
New
New
Mid-level Full Stack Software Engineer (Java/React
EASY APPLY
EASY APPLY
Junior Software Engineer - Infrastructure
Software Engineer
Software Engineer
New
New
Associate Software Engineer
C# Engineer - Full Stack
EASY APPLY
EASY APPLY
Software Engineer, Platform
Software Engineer
EASY APPLY
EASY APPLY
Software Engineer
Associate Software Engineer
Software Engineer
Software Engineer
Software Engineer - Features
EASY APPLY
EASY APPLY
 Page 1 of 81
Previous
1
2
3
4
5
Next
 People Also Searched
 Top Cities for Full Stack Engineer:  
 Top Companies for full stack engineer in Boston, MA:  
 Help / Contact Us
 Terms of Use
 Privacy & Cookies (New)
Copyright © 2008–2019, Glassdoor, Inc. "Glassdoor" and logo are proprietary trademarks of Glassdoor, Inc.
 Email me jobs for:
Create a Job Alert
Your job alert has been created.
Create more job alerts for related jobs with one click:
```

Comment: Beautifulsoup doesn't load dynamically rendered content (that by Javascript), which is common on more and more websites

Comment: What do you want to scrape from that page?

Comment: Ah ok. I'm looking for text buried deep in the body tag labeled: ```<div class="jobDescriptionContent desc">```

Comment: I think selenium might do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are ids you can extract from that page and concatenate into an url that the page uses to retrieve json which populates the card on right as you scroll. Handle the json to extract what ever info you want.

Finding the urls - the right hand side updates content as you scroll down on the left, so I went hunting in the network tab for the activity associated with the update. When I saw the new urls, generated during scrolling, it looked like there were common strings and parts that varied i.e. likely a querystring format. I guessed that the parts that varied came from the page (and some looked like generated ids we could keep static/ignore  - an experience based assumption I tested). I went hunting in the html for what I expected were the important identifiers for differentiating jobs to the server i.e. the two sets of ids. You take either of the two ids being concatenated in url string from the network tab and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to search the page HTML for them; you will see where these values come from.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import re

results = []
with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'https://www.glassdoor.co.uk/Job/json/details.htm?pos=&ao={}&s=58&guid=0000016a88f962649d396c5b606d567b&src=GD_JOB_AD&t=SR&extid=1&exst=OL&ist=&ast=OL&vt=w&slr=true&cs=1_1d8f42ad&cb=1557076206569&jobListingId={}&gdToken=uo8hehXn6nNuwhjMyBW14w:3RBFWgOD-0e7hK8o-Fgo0bUtD6jw5wJ3UujVq6L-v0ux9mlLjMxjW8-KF9xsDk41j7I11QHOHgcj9LBoWYaCxg:wAFOqHzOjgAxIGQVmbyibsaECrQO-HWfxb8Ugq-x_tU'
    headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    r = s.get('https://www.glassdoor.co.uk/Job/boston-full-stack-engineer-jobs-SRCH_IL.0,6_IC1154532_KO7,26.htm?jl=3188635682&s=58&pos=102&src=GD_JOB_AD&srs=MY_JOBS&guid=0000016a8432102e99e9b5232325d3d5&ao=599212&countryRedirect=true', headers = headers)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    ids = [item['data-ad-order-id'] for item in soup.select('[data-ad-order-id]')]
    p1 = re.compile(r"jobIds':\[(.*)'segmentType'", re.DOTALL)
    init = p1.findall(r.text)[0]
    p2 = re.compile(r"(\d{10})")
    job_ids = p2.findall(init)
    loop_var = list(zip(ids, job_ids))

    for x, y in loop_var:
        data = s.get(url.format(x,y), headers = headers).json()
        results.append(data)
```

Comment: This is good, but I don't understand how you got that concatenated url. I don't know much about javascript.

Comment: @Bugbeeb Note added above. It was observation and some intuition based on experience of how many sites update their content.

Answer (score 0):

I found this alternative solution with selenium and chromium

```
import bs4
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\username\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)

html = driver.page_source
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

for tag in soup.find_all("div", class_="jobDescriptionContent desc"):
    print (tag.text)
```